# Symfony2 can't save to the database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a strange problem with saving to the database in Symfony2 controller. Here is the code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
//$cars is taken from the entity and is not null
foreach($cars as $car) {
    $car->setHasContent('yes');
    $em->persist($car);
    $em->flush();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::getManager()
```

I can fix this by changing $em to:

```
$em = $this->get("doctrine.orm.entity_manager");
```

But then I get this error and don't know why (500 error):

```
ObjectManager does not support filters
```

Any ideas why?

If it helps anyone there is Gedmo Doctrine Extension installed, and the error points to:

```
vendor/gedmo-doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Sluggable/SluggableListener.php at line 523
throw new \Gedmo\Exception\InvalidArgumentException("ObjectManager does not support filters");
```

Comment: Which version of Symfony 2/Doctrine 2 do you have?  It is very mysterious.  I suspect you may have more code going on here that you are showing.

Comment: Please can you share the app/config/config.yml , precisely you doctrine entry.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are calling the manager from a controller, so I think you may have forgotten to make your class extends Controller.

```
class myClass extends Controller
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: How could he call the function get('myservice') if he don't extend the basecontroller.... ?

Comment: No, I extend the Controller class